# How to take max row in a window in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   team_id  player_id  score
0  1        1          3
1  1        2          6
2  1        3          2
3  2        1          10
4  2        2          8
```

I would like to extract the *rows* of the top players in each team by *score*:

```
   team_id  player_id  score
1  1        2          6
3  2        1          10
```

How do I do this? Is there a function like "window" for Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Try `groupby` and `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('team_id')['score'].idxmax()]

   team_id  player_id  score
1        1          2      6
3        2          1     10
```

Comment: aha change a new name :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben New day, new me!

Answer (score 3):

`sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('score').drop_duplicates(['team_id'],keep='last')
Out[576]: 
   team_id  player_id  score
1        1          2      6
3        2          1     10
```

Comment: `sort` takes nlog(n) time. I wonder what's the complexity of `groupby`?

Comment: @MiloLu you can try the timing on your side , Base on my experience seems like sort_values + drop_duplicates should be ok .

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transform` in combination with `groupby` and `max`:

```
df[df['score'] == df.groupby('team_id')['score'].transform('max')]

   team_id  player_id  score
1        1          2      6
3        2          1     10
```